# How can I use jq to sort by datetime field?

Tags: json, sorting, datetime, jq

```
[
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "items": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "count": 603,
      "firstTimestamp": "2018-06-07T13:07:32Z",
      "involvedObject": {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "Pod",
        "name": "events-db8f675c6-khm4r",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "2989590",
        "uid": "bd489878-6a53-11e8-9351-0e5486765cbc"
      },
      "kind": "Event",
      "lastTimestamp": "2018-06-07T16:02:52Z"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

How could I sort all the `items` (there is only one item above - but it's just an example) by the `.items.lasttimestamp` value, for example the value `"lastTimestamp": "2018-06-07T11:59:53Z"`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**`jq`** approach:

```
jq '.[].items |= sort_by(.lastTimestamp)' input.json
```

Reference: [jq Manual (development version)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sort,sort_by(path_expression))

Comment: Hmm this gives me an error of: ```jq: error: Cannot update field at string index of string
jq: error: Cannot index array with string
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: null and array cannot be sorted, as they are not both arrays
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: null and array cannot be sorted, as they are not both arrays
null
```

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, make sure that you have posted the actual input structure

Comment: I've updated with a simplified example in my answer.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, that's not simplified, that's different structure. The 1st one was an array, this one is an object

Comment: I might have messed something up, apologies. This seems to work though: `jq '.items |= sort_by(.lastTimestamp)'`

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, that's ok

Comment: to reverse the order you can filter through the jq command reverse
`jq '.[].items |= sort_by(.lastTimestamp) | reverse' input.json`

Comment: Does sort_by works with unix timestamp ?