# jq - Get objects with latest date

Tags: jq

Json looks like this:

```
cat test.json |jq -r ".nodes[].run_data"

  {   
    "id": "1234",   
    "status": "PASSED",
    "penultimate_status": "PASSED",   
    "end_time":"2022-02-28T09:50:05Z" 
  } 
  {
    "id": "4321",   
    "status": "PASSED",  
    "penultimate_status": "UNKNOWN",
    "end_time": "2020-10-14T13:52:57Z"
 }
```

I want to get "status" and "end_time" of the newest run. Unfortunately the order is not fix. Meaning the newest run can be first in the list, but also last or in the middle...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use jq to sort by datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741593/how-can-i-use-jq-to-sort-by-datetime-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `max_by` to retrieve the item with the highest predicate value. Alternatively, use `sort_by` to bring the items in order along that predicate, then extract the last item using either `last` or the position `-1`:

```bash
jq '
  [.nodes[].run_data]
  | max_by(.end_time)
      # or: sort_by(.end_time) | last
      # or: sort_by(.end_time)[-1]
  | {status, end_time}
' test.json
```

```json
{
  "status": "PASSED",
  "end_time": "2022-02-28T09:50:05Z"
}
```

---

To generate a formatted output, replace `{status, end_time}` with an accordingly formatted string, e.g. `"\(.end_time): Status \(.status)"`, and set the `-r` flag for a JSON-decoded (raw) output.

Comment: Why don't you ever mark a question as duplicate?

Comment: @0stone0 The only reason to do so, according to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is to "save myself some frustration". I cannot find any other reason mentioned. And, honestly, it gives me a lot of satisfaction to help others, instead of splitting hairs whether this special case is or is not a duplicate, and so on. This, somehow, is only frustrating others. Although sharing some similarities, in the end a Q&A platform is not the same as a reference book. You may go on and close this question now, my only goal was to help someone get their answer.

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) says: "*n a nutshell: If a question is a duplicate of another question, flag or vote to close.*". You can create a community answer if you really want to help OP but having the same questions does not help SO/

Comment: @0stone0 Your post also answers "Should I answer it?" with "Generally, no, not if you think it's a duplicate. That said, try to look at the proposed target from the perspective and perceived skill level of the asker." That's exactly what I'm doing. It's left to me how I **think** what it is. And I most often don't think that questions are 100% duplicate (with certain exceptions and YMMV). I am looking "from the perspective and perceived skill level of the asker" and think: If they had the approach and success to find a solution from a similar, maybe even duplicate question, they wouldn't ask.

Comment: Note that this only works if all timestamps use the same offset. This is the case in the sample data provided, but the format in question (RFC 3339) allows for offsets other than `Z` to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transpose` to map each object with its end_time.

Here I have converted `end_time` to seconds since Unix epoch and outputted the object with largest seconds value (this is the newest).

```
[
[. | map(.end_time | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") | mktime), [.[0], .[1]]] 
| transpose[] 
| .[1] += {secs: .[0]} | .[1]
] 
| sort_by(.secs) | last 
| {status, end_time}
```

Output

```
{
  "status": "PASSED",
  "end_time": "2022-02-28T09:50:05Z"
}
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/w1z2n2drc7